# Linking models in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I"m building a Rails app, and there are two models that I want to connect.

There's a model called "users" that handles user authentication, e.g. username and password data. Then there's a model called "profiles" that has a person's location, description, etc, etc.

I want to link the models so that there's one profile per user.  I really don't know how to do this. Anyone mind sharing some insight on how this can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at [rails associations basics](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

your asociation will look like

```
class User < AR:Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < AR:Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

oh, the table profiles must have a user_id column with the foreign key to the user.

Comment: Thanks!  Now, if you don't mind another noob-ish question, how do I have a user_id column with a foreign key to the user?

Comment: you have to create a migration to tell rails to add a column 'user_id' in the table profiles, then it takes care of all. Check this out http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Rails sure takes care of a lot of things automagically. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You want a has_one and belongs_to association on your User model and your Profile model.  Your profile model will likely have a user_id column and will be the "belongs_to" relationship, while the User will have no column for the profile and will be the "has_one" relationship.

Then in your code you can do this:

```
profile = some_user.profile
```

or

```
user = some_profile.user
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a one-to-one association. Here's how you would set it up:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Rails makes this kind of relationship super simple. :)

Make sure the Profiles table has a user_id column so this association will work.