# How do I use the associations that I create in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This feels like it should be really obvious; sorry if it is.

I created two scaffolds in rails: `Teams` and `Players`. Got that working no problem. I wanted to link them up though, since a `Team` has many `Players` and `Players` belong to a `Team`. So I went into the respective models and created the association. I read around and saw that I'd have to create a new column in `Players` to house the foreign key, so I did that with a migration; I called it `team_id` and updated 4 of the 5 records I'd created to give an ID of `1`. Basically, what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4823335/945370) instructed.

What I don't understand now is, how do I use that association? So, to get a specific example, how would I list all of the `Players` in `Team`'s show.html.erb model based on that team's ID? Do I need to call `Players` in my controller somehow?

---

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130303052538) do

  create_table "players", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "position"
    t.integer  "number"
    t.integer  "grade"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "middle_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.integer  "team_id"
  end

  create_table "teams", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

end
```

Models (lumped 'em together here for brevity):

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :grade, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :number, :position, :team_id

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  # Relationships
  has_many :players
end
```

Part of my `Team` controller:

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @team }
    end
  end

end
```

View:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @team.name %>
  <%= @team.id %>
</p>
<p>
  <b>Players:</b>
  # I want to list them here.

</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_team_path(@team) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', teams_path %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read the doc over here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

You can access the player's team with:

```
player.team
```

And you can access the team's player with:

```
team.players
```

and then iterate over these players in the view

```
team.players.each do |player|

end
```

The class methods like `belongs_to` and `has_many` you called in your model will generate methods for you.

For instance, `belongs_to :team` will generate: `team`, `team=(team)`, `build_team(attributes)`, `create_team(attributes)` etc...

Comment: Cool! Thanks for that resource. Got it to work with @team instead of team. How did it find `team_id`...would it have guessed the right column to be the foreign key if I had called it anything else?

Comment: No, it wouldn't have worked. It guesses the foreign key name from the association name. You have an option to customize the foreign key. Btw, in the migration, you could have used `t.references :team`, instead of `t.integer :user_id`, it's the same thing.