# How to create a new model that is connected to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I create a new model documents that is connected to model users, such that users have many documents? This should be done using the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking models in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823307/linking-models-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: "This should be done using the console" makes this sound like a homework question. Homework questions are fine, but like any other question on this site you should at least show that you've made an effort to answer it independently, explain why you're stuck, and what you've tried to get unstuck. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is basic asked in tidious way,

Type following in rails console,

```
class user
  has_many :documents
end
```

provided by `documents` table will have `user_id` foreign_key. then you can connect documents by user object.

Answer (score 0):

```
# bash
rails generate model document user:belongs_to

# then just modify app/models/user.rb, and add `has_many :documents`
```

Comment: `rails g model Document user:references` model will contain `belongs_to` already and the migration will include the indexing

Comment: @engineersmnky From what I know they create exactly the same migration file; both also add `belongs_to :user` to the model file. I just prefer to use `:belongs_to` because it is more readable to me.

Comment: My apologies you are correct `add_belongs_to` is an `alias` of `add_reference`

Comment: @engineersmnky no worries at all! :) It's better that my assumption was validated, because I've never really tested if they are indeed the same haha Good to know

Comment: can you check this post too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766842/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-put-for-ajax-call

Comment: @KickButtowski sure, I'll see what I can do :)